# How to sort an array by some specific key?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array look like below.

```
$array[0]['keyword']  = 'cricket ';
$array[0]['noofhits'] = '26';

$array[1]['keyword']  = 'food  ';
$array[1]['noofhits'] = '17';

$array[2]['keyword']  = 'mypax';
$array[2]['noofhits'] = '22';

$array[3]['keyword']  = 'next';
$array[3]['noofhits'] = '22';

$array[4]['keyword']  = 'nextbutton';
$array[4]['noofhits'] = '22';

$array[5]['keyword']  = 'picture';
$array[5]['noofhits'] = '18';
```

I want to sort the array using the noofhits. How can I do? Advance Thanks for your advice.

Soory for the previous one.Thanks for your answers.

Comment: With this exact code, you only have only have an array with one element.

Comment: Am I seeing things..? Your code is overwriting its data.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) with a custom comparison function:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return $a['noofhits'] - $b['noofhits'];
}
usort($array, 'cmp');
```

`usort` expects the comparison function to return three different value:

- 0 if *a* and *b* are equal
- integer less than 0 if *a* precedes *b*
- integer greater than 0 if *b* precedes *a*

So we can simply subtract the value of *b* from *a*. If *a*’s value is greater than *b*’s value, the subtraction yields a positive integer; if *a*’s value is equal to *b*’s value, it yields 0; and if *a*’s value is less than *b*’s value, it yields a negative value.