# Sorting an array by a key - PHP

Tags: php, sorting

I have a program that allows users to add an proposal to a review board. I passed in a firstname and a proposal message from a form, stored it into a string, and stored it into an indexed array. I'm very new to PHP.

Example of the string:

```
$text = "UserName:$user<br/>Proposal:$prop";
```

When displayed it looks like:

UserName: "  "

Proposal: "  "

UserName: "  "

Proposal: "  "

I'd like to give the user the option to sort alphabetically by username:

The array looks like:

```
$arr=array(
0 => UserName:bfoo<br/>Proposal:foo foo
1 => UserName:afoo<br/>Proposal:foo foo
2 => UserName:cfoo<br/>Proposal:foo foo)
```

After sorting by username I want it to look like:

```
 $arr=array(
0 => UserName:afoo<br/>Proposal:foo foo
1 => UserName:bfoo<br/>Proposal:foo foo
2 => UserName:cfoo<br/>Proposal:foo foo)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort an array by some specific key?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627677/how-to-sort-an-array-by-some-specific-key)

Comment: Did you try Googling something like "[How to sort an array in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)"?

Comment: Use a mutlidimensional array containing username and corresponding proposal .Now sort the values and then enter it into the string ($text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {

$lines_a = explode("<br/>", $a);
$lines_b = explode("<br/>", $b);

return strcmp(str_replace("UserName:", "", $lines_a[0]), str_replace("UserName:", "", $lines_b[0]));
});
```

However, if you sort by the values, it is going to give you the correct result as well (Because the UserName: string is identical in all the values and we don't really care what's after the names.

So just use this: [sort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) .

Comment: The strings that make up the user's array has the Username as the first dynamic value. A simple `sort()` function will do for sorting this array alphabetically.

Comment: Indeed, I overlooked

Comment: For some reason the asort and normal sort didn't work for me. Usernames that began with R were still showing up before Usernames that began with K. The usort by @molbal actually worked out.